# Python time vs datetime vs mxDateTime

Tags: python

WHy would I choose to use Python's time vs datetime (and also mxDateTime) when either way you can get the same result? For example,

```
time.localtime()[7]
datetime.date.today().timetuple()[7]
```

yields the same, mxDateTime can also produce same result.

Answer (score 2):

You can check which one is faster by using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/timeit.html) package in python.

```
import sys
import timeit
import datetime
import time

def create_datetime():
    return datetime.date.today().timetuple()

def create_time():
    return time.localtime()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeit.timeit("create_datetime()", setup="from __main__ import create_datetime"))
    print(timeit.timeit("create_time()", setup="from __main__ import create_time"))
```

It prints:

```
3.7883488804446963
0.4524141759797713
```

So, it looks like `time.localtime()` is better than `datetime.date.today()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, from my knowledge, you can use any of the two. It just depends which module you'd be using most, so you don't have unneeded functions lying around.